# Data is not displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am relatively new to json and javascript. I have written some javascript that is suppose to get the data from from a json file and displaying it in a div tag.

The following code is the javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax(
    { 
    type:'GET',     
    url:"json/desktop.json",  
    success:function(desktop)   { 
        var data = [];

            for (var i=0; i<desktop.Windows8Pc.desktop.length; i++)   { 
                var desktops = desktop.Windows8Pc.desktop[i];
                data.push(desktops);
                content = "<p>" + desktops.model + "</p>";
                $(content).appendTo("#div1");

                }


        }
    });

    });
    </script>
```

The Json file contains something like this

```
    "desktops":
{
    "Windows8Pc":
    {
        "desktop":
        [
            {
                "ID":"1",
                "Make":"HP",
                "model": "Pavilion 500-250ea",
                "Price": "679.99",
                "CPU": "Core i5-4440",
                "OS": "Windows 8.1",
                "RAM": "8",
                "HDD": "2000",
                "SSD": "",
                "GPU":"",
                "Screen":"",
                "Image": "1.jpg",
                "stock": "10"
            }, ....
```

The following code is the html code

```
<div id="div1"></div>
```

Can someone help pls? I pretty sure it is some idiotic  bug I can't see it

Comment: Can you post what `desktop` is in the response?

Comment: The desktop json basically contains something like this   "desktops":
 {
  "Windows8Pc":
  {
   "desktop":
   [
    {
     "ID":"1",
     "Make":"HP",
     "model": "Pavilion 500-250ea",
     "Price": "679.99",
     "CPU": "Core i5-4440",
     "OS": "Windows 8.1",
     "RAM": "8",
     "HDD": "2000",
     "SSD": "",
     "GPU":"",
     "Screen":"",
     "Image": "1.jpg",
     "stock": "10"
    }  .....

Comment: What is `item.name`? There is no reference to item in the code. Also, your `for` loop does not have have exit condition.

Comment: changed it to desktops.Model but still nothing

Comment: and changed the for to for (var i=0; i<desktop.Windows8Pc.desktop.length; i++)

Comment: Have you confirmed that it's looping through the data?  Add an alert or console of the length of `desktop.Windows8Pc.desktop` to make sure that the response is coming back as object, I bet you it's coming back as a string.  I would suggest switching to `$.getJSON` -> http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post your full JSON data, but one problem appears to be that "desktops" in the JSON is a *property* of the top-level JSON object. But you're using it as if "desktops" *is* the top-level object.

Does the JSON data actually look something like this?

```
{
    "desktops": {
        "Windows8Pc": {
            "desktop": [
                {
                    "ID":"1",
                    ...
                },
                ...
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you should add `dataType: 'json'` to your `$.ajax()` call to make sure the incoming data is parsed as JSON.

In the original code, there is a `desktops` variable whose name implies that it is a plural thing - but it isn't, it's the name of a single machine specification. And the names in the JSON data are poor: `desktop` is an array, but its name implies that it is a *single* desktop.

Of course you may just have to live with the bad names in the JSON data, but at least you can choose names in your own code that make more sense. Use plural names for arrays, singular names for individual objects or other items.

To avoid confusion, I avoided the words `desktops` and `desktop` completely for variable names, and instead used `machines` for the array of machine objects (the `desktop` array in the JSON data), and `machine` for a single one of these machine objects.

Using this `machines` variable helps us avoid the repeated reference `desktop.Windows8Pc.desktop`. This is a simple case here, but in more complex code you can dramatically simplify it by saving variable references to deeply nested objects like these.

Another tip: Instead of repeatedly appending to the DOM, it's generally better for performance to append to a string of HTML text, and then when done append or insert the entire HTML string into the DOM.

Finally, you might use `$.each()` instead of the `for` loop to make the code a little cleaner.

So the code might look like this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "json/desktop.json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function( json ) {
            var html = '';
            var machines = json.desktops.Windows8Pc.desktop;
            $.each( machines, function( i, machine ) {
                html += "<p>" + machine.model + "</p>";
            });
            $("#div1").html( html );
        }
    });
});
```

BTW I removed the `data` array and the `data.push(machine);` statement, because there is no need for those. The `machines` array above already *is* the same thing as that `data` array: an array of the individual machine objects.

---

Now for some much more valuable advice: The real problem here is that you haven't yet learned how to debug JavaScript. That's OK, but it's time to learn! Once you know how to debug JavaScript, you will be able to solve problems like this on your own, much faster than asking for help here.

There are many resources to help you learn how to debug JavaScript. A simple Google search for "debug javascript" will find a bunch of them, including articles on the [Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging), [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/javascript), and many more.

Here is a version of the code above with a couple of strategically placed `debugger` statements:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "json/desktop.json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function( json ) {
            debugger;
            var html = '';
            var machines = json.desktops.Windows8Pc.desktop;
            $.each( machines, function( i, machine ) {
                debugger;
                html += "<p>" + machine.model + "</p>";
            });
            $("#div1").html( html );
        }
    });
});
```

Run this version with the Chrome developer tools open, and it will stop on each of the `debugger` statements. When it stops, you can look at the relevant variables: at the first `debugger` statement you can inspect the `json` variable, and you can experiment with things in the console. If you type `json.desktops.Windows8Pc.desktop` in the console here, does it display what you expect (an array of machine data objects)? If not, look closely at the `json` variable and see what is actually in it.

And at the second `debugger` statement you can inspect the `machine` variable in the same way. Is `machine` an object? Does it have a `machine.model` property? Again you can view both of those in the variables panel or by typing them into the console.

Comment: THanks for you advice. Yes, the Json does look something like that, for some reason the javascript still is not working

Comment: See my advice at the end of the answer. If the JavaScript code is not working "for some reason", you *can* find that reason. I would start with the Chrome developer tools, and learn how to set breakpoints, single step through your code, and inspect variables as you go. If you do that, you *will* find what's wrong, I guarantee it.

Comment: I added some specific debugging tips to the answer. Seriously, spend some time learning the Chrome developer tools. I am not exaggerating a bit: this is like gaining a superpower!

Comment: And did you add the `dataType: "json"`? Without it you may be getting the JSON as plain text, not as an object. Or use `$.getJSON()` which adds that for you (but doesn't let you provide an `error` callback should you want that later).

Comment: Yes, so I have taken your advice and started debugging and playing around and added an case error function, this error is being created [object Object] ____ parsererror_______SyntaxError: Unexpected token